# Optimizing a c# program that creates 2 dictionaries and searches both for a matching value

Tags: c#

I have 2 Dictionaries. I am trying to optimize this code to run as fast as possible.

This is for solving Shanks Baby Step Giant Step Algorithm
Algorithm:

```
Given b = a^x (mod p)
First choose n, such that n^2 >= p-1
Then create 2 lists:
    1. a^j (mod p) for 0 <= j < n
    2. b*(a(inverse)^n)^k for 0 <= k < n
Finally look for a match between the 2 lists.


public static BigInteger modInverse(BigInteger a, BigInteger n)
{
    BigInteger i = n, v = 0, d = 1;
    while (a > 0)
    {
        BigInteger t = i / a, x = a;
        a = i % x;
        i = x;
        x = d;
        d = v - t * x;
        v = x;
    }
    v %= n;
    if (v < 0) v = (v + n) % n;
    return v;
}

static int Main()
{
    BigInteger r = 92327518017225,
               rg,
               temp,
               two=2,
               tm, 
               n = ((BigInteger)Math.Sqrt(247457076132467-1))+1, 
               mod = 247457076132467;
    Dictionary<int, BigInteger> b = new Dictionary<int, BigInteger>();
    Dictionary<int, BigInteger> g = new Dictionary<int, BigInteger>();
    temp = modInverse(two, mod);
    temp = BigInteger.ModPow(temp, n, mod);
    for (int j = 0; (BigInteger)j < n; j++)
    {
        rg = r * BigInteger.ModPow(temp, j, mod);
        g.Add(j, rg);
    }
    for (int i = 0; (BigInteger)i < n ; i++)
    {
        tm = BigInteger.ModPow(2, i, mod);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, BigInteger> d in g)
        {
            if (d.Value.Equals(tm))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("j={0}   B*t^j(mod m) = {1}",d.Key,d.Value);
                Console.WriteLine("a^"+i+" = "+tm);
            }
        }
        b.Add(i,tm);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not all that familiar with this particular algorithm however what is the reason for the BigIntegers? What precision do you need?

Comment: More specifically I understand why you may need BigInteger for r, rg, temp, tm however n,i,j I don't believe should be cast to BigInteger so the question is what is the range of n?

Comment: Why are you using a Dictionary at all?  You are simply storing keys contiguous from 0-n, i.e., you are using a Dictionary as an array.

Answer (score 2):

There are some really obvious optimisations.

1. Delete all the code relating to `b`. A dictionary you only insert into is a waste of time, memory, and programmer ability to understand what's going on.
2. Use `g` as a dictionary. The way to do that is to change it from a `Dictionary<int, BigInteger>` into a `Dictionary<BigInteger, int>`. Then your `foreach` can be replaced with a simple `TryGetValue`.
3. Ditch the cast of `j` to BigInteger:

   ```
   int n_int = ((int)Math.Sqrt(247457076132467-1))+1;
   ... 
   n = (BigInteger)n_int
   ```

   And compare `j` to `n_int`. If it doesn't fit in an int, `j` shouldn't be an int either.
4. Exploit basic arithmetic properties in loops. E.g. rather than

   ```
   tm = BigInteger.ModPow(2, i, mod);
   ```

   you should have

   ```
   tm = 1,
   ...
   for (int i = 0; i < n_int; i++)
   {
       ...
       tm = (tm * 2) % mod;
   }
   ```

PS In fact, if you'd looked at the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) on the algorithm you'd have found pseudocode which handles all this already.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can improve the speed of the search is:

- For one of the two dictionaries, construct an array of the values. Sort this array.
- To do the search:
- > Go through sequentially through the values of the other dictionary.
- > For each value, perform an Array.BinarySearch() for the value, in the sorted array to see if there is a match.

Due to the binary search, this method will reduce down to O(N log N) instead of your current brute force method which is O(N²)